# Excel VBA - Replace Null Cells in Columns C-F with Zero if Column A Contains a Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data-set that contains 7 columns. I am trying to write a macro that looks to see if column A is not null, if it isn't null then I want to replace null cells in the corresponding C-F columns with 0. The number of records in column A will change from time to time so the macro will need to account for that.

I want this:

[image: Before_Macro]

to turn into this:

[image: After_Macro]

This seems really simple I am just very new to VBA so any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any code below which suits your need , first code will replace all blank values to 0 and the 2nd code will fill all blanks with 0 of Selected Cells.

```
Sub FillZero()
    Range("C2:F" & Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row).Replace What:="", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False
End Sub
Sub FillZero_SelectedRange()
    Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily without resorting to VBA.

- Select a cell with zero in it.
- Edit/Copy
- Select your target range
- Edit/Paste Special/Values/Add

Comment: Thank you @Lord Peter however, it needs to be done using VBA as this process is repeated each and everyday. This snippet of code I am looking for will fit into a larger macro that transforms the raw data extracts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub highlight()    
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")    
  lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    
  For i = 2 To lastrow    
    If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then    
      For t = 3 To 6    
        If ws.Cells(i, t).Value = "" Then    
          ws.Cells(i, t).Value = "0"    
        End If    
      Next t    
    End If    
  Next i    
End Sub
```